# How to get User Information from IdentityServer using Authorization Code Flow + PKCE?

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a API server and an IdentityServer project. The API server performs Authorization Code flow + PKCE using OpenId and Profile scopes. Upon successful authorization, I want to have user profile included in `User.Identity`. But I am not finding any sample tutorial neither any way to make it happen.

Comment: What do you mean by user profile?